# VBA Excel - Die and Dump a collection

Tags: vba, excel

When writing VBA, I like to have little helper methods that I can call on at particular points in the development cycle. My most useful is one inspired by Laravel's `dd($variable)` function - die and dump. In other words, spit out the output of the variable and then kill the process so no other processing takes place. I use it as a way of setting breakpoints.

Now my current custom helper can dump a variable as well as an array, but how could I get it to work for a collection too?

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Die and Dump
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function dd(value As Variant)

    Dim ArrayBoolean As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer

    ArrayBoolean = IsArray(value)

    ' Commence to dumping the data
    If ArrayBoolean = True Then
        For i = LBound(value) To UBound(value): Debug.Print (value(i)): Next
    Else
        Debug.Print (value)
    End If

    ' Now Die!
    End

End Function
```

I have tried the following:

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Die and Dump a Collection
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function ddc(value As Collection)

    Dim coll As Variant

    ' Dump
    For Each coll In value
        Debug.Print coll
    Next coll


    ' Now Die!
    End

End Function
```

But when I do `Helpers.ddc (objectsInWorkbook)` I get an `Argument not optional` error yet `Helpers.dd(objectsInWorkbook.count)` returns an integer of 5 (the amount of objects in the collection)

Comment: Why are you using a function rather than a sub ??

Comment: Quite frankly @Gary'sStudent I don't know the difference

Comment: don't use variable names like `value` , or any other vba keyword like `for`, `dim`...... I suspect in your test `objectsInWorkbook` was the wrong type (or empty), but still it would throw an other error. Something is missing in your explanation. And you can very well call a function or a sub with only one argument without using `call` or with/without `()`. The difference with a function is that you can assign to a variable : `a=dd(x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Helpers.ddc (objectsInWorkbook)
```

use

```
Helpers.ddc objectsInWorkbook
```

Comment: Good catch of the issue

Answer (score 1):

You should **Call** the function instead of just typing **Helpers.dd(objectsInWorkbook)**.

```
Call Helpers.ddc(objectsInWorkbook)
```

Comment: It's not neccessary - see the answer of Mrig. You can use **Call** but the arguments have to be in brackets. If you don't want to **Call** it you have to set the arguments without the brackets after **Helpers.ddc**.